# Create JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, object

I need to create JSON like this:

```
Order = {   type_id:'1',model_id:'1',

   transfer:{
     startDate:'10/04/2015 12:45',
     endDate:'10/04/2015 16:00',
     startPoint:'Ул. Момышулы, 45',
     endPoint:'Аэропорт Астаны'
   },
   hourly:{
     startDate:'10/04/2015',
     endDate:'11/04/2015',
     startPoint:'ЖД Вокзал',
     endPoint:'',
     undefined_time:'1'
   },
   custom:{
     startDate:'12/04/2015',
     endDate:'12/04/2015',
     startPoint:'Астана',
     endPoint:'Павлодар',
     customPrice:'50 000'
   },
    commentText:'',
    device_type:'ios'
};
```

The problem is that I can not create valid JSON. 
Here is how I create object:

```
let jsonObject: [AnyObject]  = [
        ["type_id": singleStructDataOfCar.typeID, "model_id": singleStructDataOfCar.modelID, "transfer": savedDataTransfer, "hourly": savedDataHourly, "custom": savedDataReis, "device_type":"ios"]
    ]
```

where `savedData` are dictionaries:

```
let savedData: NSDictionary = ["ServiceDataStartDate": singleStructdata.startofWork, 
"ServiceDataAddressOfReq": singleStructdata.addressOfRequest, 
"ServiceDataAddressOfDel": singleStructdata.addressOfDelivery, 
"ServiceDataDetailedText": singleStructdata.detailedText, "ServiceDataPrice": singleStructdata.priceProposed]
```

When I use only strings creating my JSON object everything works fine. However when I include dictionaries `NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value)` returns `false`. How can I create a valid dictionary?

Comment: Try to follow this tutorial https://medium.com/swift-programming/4-json-in-swift-144bf5f88ce4

Comment: Yes, red that article. That article nsdictionary only has string values. In my case var transfer, hourly, custom have many values. it is not string ... so how should I include them ?

Comment: let jsonObject: [AnyObject]  = [
            ["type_id": singleStructDataOfCar.typeID, "model_id": singleStructDataOfCar.modelID, "transfer":[
                "startDate":savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataStartDate"] as String, "EndPoint": savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataAddressOfDel"] as String, "CommentText": savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataDetailedText"] as String, "StartPoint":savedDataTransfer["ServiceDataAddressOfReq"] as String
                ]
            ]//, "hourly": savedDataHourly, "custom": savedDataReis, "device_type":"ios"]
        ]

Comment: I know this is messy code. but it also doesnt work

Comment: You can convert the dictionary into JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855074/nsdictionary-to-json-string-to-json-object-using-swiftyjson

Comment: I guess indeed one of the  `singleStructdata.*` items is not json convertible. Try each of these individually with `NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject` and you'll find your culprit.

Comment: I already found ... some of vars were nil value. how to handle them?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

One problem is that this code is not of type `Dictionary`.

```
let jsonObject: [Any]  = [
    [
         "type_id": singleStructDataOfCar.typeID,
         "model_id": singleStructDataOfCar.modelID, 
         "transfer": savedDataTransfer, 
         "hourly": savedDataHourly, 
         "custom": savedDataReis, 
         "device_type":"iOS"
    ]
]
```

The above is an `Array` of `AnyObject` with a `Dictionary` of type `[String: AnyObject]` inside of it.

Try something like this to match the JSON you provided above:

```
let savedData = ["Something": 1]

let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [ 
    "type_id": 1,
    "model_id": 1,
    "transfer": [
        "startDate": "10/04/2015 12:45",
        "endDate": "10/04/2015 16:00"
    ],
    "custom": savedData
]

let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject) // true
```

Comment: This is correct, but I want to give a shout to SwiftyJSON pod for whoever comes next.  It can be useful.

Comment: SwiftyJSON has a great implementation for this. This current answer is not valid, but, after installing SwiftyJSON, just change `[String: AnyObject` to `JSON` and it IS valid. Later on when you are trying to get the value as a Dictionary, just type `jsonData.dictionaryObject` and there you have it!

Comment: I've changed `[String: AnyObject]` to be `[String: Any]` so that the example code compiles. I originally used `AnyObject` in the above so that the `jsonObject` could have class instances inside of it.

Comment: why is jsonObject["transfer"]["startDate"] giving me error?

Comment: Here is the error: `error: type 'Any?' has no subscript members
jsonObject["transfer"]["startDate"]`

The key "transfer" gives you an `Any?` (optional `Any`); this is per the type given to `jsonObject`, which is `[String: Any]` (keys of type `String`, values of type `Any`).

Comment: Latest Swift (iOS 11.2, Feb 2018) requires modification to the let statement: let jsonObject: [Any] = [ ... etc. [AnyObject] causes compiler error: Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal.

Comment: @sammysounder pulled a Kanye West in a Stack Overflow comment. Well done.

Comment: Simply after the initial steps you can cast that dictionary to SwiftyJSON.   `let json = JSON(jsonObject)`   For more information https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 35):

For Swift 3.0, as of December 2016, this is how it worked for me:

```
let jsonObject: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

jsonObject.setValue(value1, forKey: "b")
jsonObject.setValue(value2, forKey: "p")
jsonObject.setValue(value3, forKey: "o")
jsonObject.setValue(value4, forKey: "s")
jsonObject.setValue(value5, forKey: "r")

let jsonData: NSData

do {
    jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    print("json string = \(jsonString)")                                    

} catch _ {
    print ("JSON Failure")
}
```

EDIT 2018: I now use SwiftyJSON library to save time and make my development life easier and better. Dealing with JSON natively in Swift is an unnecessary headache and pain, plus wastes too much time, and creates code which is hard to read and write, and hence prone to lots of errors.

Answer (score 12):

Creating a JSON String:

```
let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
para.setValue("bidder", forKey: "username")
para.setValue("day303", forKey: "password")
para.setValue("authetication", forKey: "action")
let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(para, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros)
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
print(jsonString)
```

Comment: It was really helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

• Swift 4.1, April 2018

Here is a **more general approach** that can be used to create a JSON string by using values from a dictionary:

```
struct JSONStringEncoder {
    /**
     Encodes a dictionary into a JSON string.
     - parameter dictionary: Dictionary to use to encode JSON string.
     - returns: A JSON string. `nil`, when encoding failed.
     */
    func encode(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) -> String? {
        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dictionary) else {
            assertionFailure("Invalid json object received.")
            return nil
        }

        let jsonObject: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        let jsonData: Data

        dictionary.forEach { (arg) in
            jsonObject.setValue(arg.value, forKey: arg.key)
        }

        do {
            jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("JSON data creation failed with error: \(error).")
            return nil
        }

        guard let jsonString = String.init(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            assertionFailure("JSON string creation failed.")
            return nil
        }

        print("JSON string: \(jsonString)")
        return jsonString
    }
}
```

**How to use it**:

```
let exampleDict: [String: Any] = [
        "Key1" : "stringValue",         // type: String
        "Key2" : boolValue,             // type: Bool
        "Key3" : intValue,              // type: Int
        "Key4" : customTypeInstance,    // type: e.g. struct Person: Codable {...}
        "Key5" : customClassInstance,   // type: e.g. class Human: NSObject, NSCoding {...}
        // ... 
    ]

    if let jsonString = JSONStringEncoder().encode(exampleDict) {
        // Successfully created JSON string.
        // ... 
    } else {
        // Failed creating JSON string.
        // ...
    }
```

Note: If you are adding instances of your custom types (structs) into the dictionary make sure your types conform to the `Codable` protocol and if you are adding objects of your custom classes into the dictionary make sure your classes inherit from `NSObject` and conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: also if you describe how to use, the user who see can understand easy.

Comment: @HardikThakkar It's quite straight forward. I've edited the answer with How to use snippet.

Comment: @Baran Emre how would you decode  deocde jsonString into a [String:Any] dict?

Comment: @BaranEmre just to add to add to last question, the json I'm encoding have arbitrarily valued keys of type String. Think userIds generated by some service.

Comment: @chibro2 You want to create a Dictionary from a JSON String, right? If yes, then do the following: `let data: Data! = yourString.data(using: .utf8)` and then `let dictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]`.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5** - 6/30/21

Adopt the Codable protocol (similar to interface in other programming languages)

```
struct ConfigRequestBody: Codable {
var systemid: String
var password: String
var request: String = "getconfig"

init(systemID: String, password: String){
    self.systemid = systemID
    self.password = password
 }
}
```

Create instance of struct/class that you want to turn into JSON:

```
let requestBody = ConfigRequestBody(systemID: systemID, password: password)
```

Encode the object into JSON using a `JSONEncoder`. Here I print the string representation so you can see the result:

```
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    do {
        let result = try encoder.encode(requestBody)
        // RESULT IS NOW JSON-LIKE DATA OBJECT
        if let jsonString = String(data: result, encoding: .utf8){
            // JSON STRING
            print("JSON \(jsonString)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Your parsing sucks \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: In 2022, THIS needs to be the accepted answer -- ***far*** easier than what was necessary in older versions of Swift!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me... Swift 2

```
static func checkUsernameAndPassword(username: String, password: String) -> String?{
    let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        para.setValue("demo", forKey: "username")
        para.setValue("demo", forKey: "password")
       // let jsonError: NSError?
    let jsonData: NSData
    do{
        jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(para, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        print("json string = \(jsonString)")
        return jsonString

    } catch _ {
        print ("UH OOO")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://github.com/peheje/JsonSerializerSwift

Use case:

```
//Arrange your model classes
class Object {
  var id: Int = 182371823
  }
class Animal: Object {
  var weight: Double = 2.5
  var age: Int = 2
  var name: String? = "An animal"
  }
class Cat: Animal {
  var fur: Bool = true
}

let m = Cat()

//Act
let json = JSONSerializer.toJson(m)

//Assert
let expected = "{\"fur\": true, \"weight\": 2.5, \"age\": 2, \"name\": \"An animal\", \"id\": 182371823}"
stringCompareHelper(json, expected) //returns true
```

Currently supports standard types, optional standard types, arrays, arrays of nullables standard types, array of custom classes, inheritance, composition of custom objects.

Comment: i have a json which has one property which itself is an array of a custom object. When running through JsonSerialization.toJson, this loses the values and I am getting something like: "key": [{},{}] any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: It works with array of custom objects check the GitHub test file for an example of how to do this. The test case is called test_arrayOfCustomClass_included

Comment: I switched my struct to a class and it worked. Any support for structs as custom objects?

Answer (score -1):

Use SwiftyJSON to generate JSON string. Learn from the `comments` of [the answer of Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516706/419348).

@2022/10

```
let savedData = ["Something": 1]

var json = JSON()

json.dictionaryObject = [ 
    "type_id": 1,
    "model_id": 1,
    "transfer": [
        "startDate": "10/04/2015 12:45",
        "endDate": "10/04/2015 16:00"
    ],
    "custom": savedData
]

let jsonStr = json.rawString()
```