# Building JSON dynamically in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to build some JSON in Swift. I've seen some examples of turning a Dictionary into JSON or a class into JSON, but I want to be able to turn data into JSON on the fly. I also have multiple objects I want to store, not just one (which most examples I find seem to do).

Here is my code that creates dictionaries of the objects I want to store:

```
for topic in topics{

                var relEntries = getRelevantEntries(topic.id)
                var entryItem:[String:Any] = ["":""]
                for entry in relEntries{
                    var eId = ["id":entry.id]
                    var eTitle = ["title":entry.title]
                    entryItem = [
                        "id":entry.id,
                        "title":entry.title
                    ]
                }
                var topicItem:[String:Any] = [
                    "id":topic.id,
                    "topicName":topic.name,
                    "entries":entryItem
                ]
            }
```

I want to create a JSON Array, where each object includes an int, string, and another JSON Array. I wrote out a demo table to clarify.

```
[
 {   id: "id",
     topicName: "topicName",
     entries:[
          { id: "id", title: "title" },
          { id: "id2", title: "title2"}
          ]},
  {  id: "id2",
     topicName: "topicName2",
     entries:[
          { id: "id", title: "title" },
          { id: "id2", title: "title2"}
          ]}
 ]
```

So where do I go from here to combine all my topics into one JSON Array? Thanks.

Comment: @matt, as far as I understood OP, he does search for a more generic, probably reflection-based, way of doing said trivial grunt work for him for a rather large amount of to-be-json-converted classes.

Comment: @matt, I'm new to iOS and Swift. I'm learning by looking at other people's answers on SO. I found a single example that looks just like mine and when I try to set my array of topics to [String:AnyObject] instead of the [String:Any] it is now, I'm told I'm being too ambiguous. And you need an AnyObject item to run NSJSONSerialization. Here is that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512839/create-json-in-swift

Comment: Have you looked at SwiftyJSON?

Comment: "And you need an AnyObject item" Every class instance is an AnyObject instance.

Comment: TravisGriggs I'm attempting this without an additional library if possible.
@matt I didn't realize AnyObject is the Swift version of Java's Object. Thanks for teaching me that. When I try to run "NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(topicItem)" I'm told argument type '[String:Any]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

Comment: @matt I have no idea what kind of tone you're getting from my comments, but I'm not trying to thrash out anything. I'm trying to understand how to generate an array of JSON objects as opposed to just a single object. Over the course of these comments I've learned that the problem may begin with being told the [String:AnyObject] is too ambiguous, so I'm going to look into that now.

Comment: "I'm trying to understand how to generate an array of JSON objects as opposed to just a single object" Really? That's not what your question says. Your question says you want to generate a single JSON object representing an array — which is very easy to do, since all you have to do is start with an array..

Comment: I thought I was clear when I said "I also have multiple objects I want to store, not just one (which most examples I find seem to do)". You can see my end game in the JSON code I post. Regardless, you have no obligation to help me. If you don't plan to help, please stop commenting.

Comment: But as I said at the outset, generating your end game is trivial. This is why it is hard to see what the question can be. I've added an answer that actually does it, to show you how simple it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialization techniques on your custom objects to build Foundation types that represent them.

After that, you can use the [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/) class to generate the json.

Since you have to differentiate between your different classes, there is less except [handling with mirrors](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) that might generalize that work for you at this point in time, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I want to create a JSON Array, where each object includes an int, string, and another JSON Array. I wrote out a demo table to clarify.

```
[
 {   id: "id",
     topicName: "topicName",
     entries:[
          { id: "id", title: "title" },
          { id: "id2", title: "title2"}
          ]},
  {  id: "id2",
     topicName: "topicName2",
     entries:[
          { id: "id", title: "title" },
          { id: "id2", title: "title2"}
          ]}
 ]
```

Well, what is that? It's an array (`[...]`) of dictionaries (`{...}`), where each dictionary has an `id` key (with a string value), a `topicName` key (with a string value), and an `entries` key, where each `entries` value is an array containing two dictionaries with an `id` key and a `title` key (each with a string value).

So your job is merely to construct that structure and serialize it into JSON. That's trivial. Here, as a mockup, I'll demonstrate using literals:

```
var d1 : [NSObject:AnyObject] = ["id":"id", "topicName":"topicName"]
var d2 : [NSObject:AnyObject] = ["id":"id2", "topicName":"topicName2"]
let dd1 = ["id":"id", "title":"title"]
let dd2 = ["id":"id2", "title":"title2"]
let arr1 = [dd1,dd2]
let arr2 = [dd1,dd2]
d1["entries"] = arr1
d2["entries"] = arr2
let arr = [d1,d2]
let d = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arr, options: [])
let s = NSString(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(s!)
```

Output:

```
[
 {"id":"id",
  "entries":[
    {"id":"id","title":"title"},   
    {"id":"id2","title":"title2"}
  ],
  "topicName":"topicName"
  },
  {"id":"id2",
  "entries":[
    {"id":"id","title":"title"},
    {"id":"id2","title":"title2"}
  ],
  "topicName":"topicName2"
  }
 ]
```

I believe you'll find that that's exactly the equivalent of what you asked for. Now all you have to do is write code that converts your original data structure into the data structure that I constructed above out of literals.