# how to create json object in swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift

how can i create this json :

```
{"orderItems":"[{\"product_id\":19,\"quantity\":2,\"size_key\":\" 39 40 42\"},"retailer_id":20,"status":"initial"}
```

here is code :--

```
let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
let prodArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
para.setValue(20 , forKey: "retailer_id")
para.setValue("initial", forKey: "status")

for product in colorsArray {
  let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
  prod.setValue(product.product?["id"] , forKey: "product_id")
  prod.setValue("1", forKey: "quantity")
  prod.setValue(variabledata, forKey: "size_key")
  prodArray.add(prod)
}

para.setValue(20 , forKey: "retailer_id")
para.setValue("initial", forKey: "status")
```

Comment: Perhaps this would help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516706/9462397 . It is a lot like typescript.

Comment: this does not contain array

Comment: That's not valid json.

Comment: That being said, I would use the `Codable` protocol for this.

Comment: At least never use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about JSON but according to giving JSON and code part.

JSON should be `{"orderItems" : [{"product_id" : 19 , "quantity" : 2 , "size_key" : "39 40 42"}],"retailer_id":20,"status":"initial"}`

JSON creator code:

```
var para : [String:Any] = [String:Any]()
var prodArray : [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()

para["retailer_id"] = 20
para["initial"] = "status"

for product in colorsArray {
    var prod : [String : Any] = [String : Any]()
    if let productId = product.product?["id"] {
         prod["product_id"] = productId
    }

    prod["quantity"] = "1"
    prod["size_key"] = variabledata

    prodArray.append(prod)
}

para["orderItems"] = prodArray
print(para)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this version:

```
// MARK: - DataStructure
struct DataStructure: Codable {
    let orderItems: [OrderItem]
}

// MARK: - OrderItem
struct OrderItem: Codable {
    let productID, quantity: Int
    let sizeKey: String
    let retailerID: Int
    let status: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productID = "product_id"
        case quantity
        case sizeKey = "size_key"
        case retailerID = "retailer_id"
        case status
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add the encoding part.

Comment: how can i use this please elaborate it .

Answer (score 1):

You want a JSON string inside a JSON string. To accomplish that you have to encode only the array, then add the value to the dictionary and call `JSONSerialization` a second time.

Referring to your answer replace

```
para["orderItems"] =   ("\(prodArray)")

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para )
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

(By the way please never use that horrible `NSString` syntax in Swift)

with

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: prodArray)
let arrayString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
para["orderItems"] = arrayString
let resultData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para)
let jsonString = String(data: resultData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var para : [String:Any] = [String:Any]()
var prodArray : [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()

para["retailer_id"] = 20
para["status"] = "initial"

for product in colorsArray {
    var prod : [String : Any] = [String : Any]()
    if let productId = product.product?["id"] {
         prod["product_id"] = productId
    }

    prod["quantity"] =  1
    prod["size_key"] = variabledata

    prodArray.append(prod)
}

para["orderItems"] =   ("\(prodArray)")

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para )
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

output I'm getting ===

```
{"orderItems":[{"product_id":19,"size_key":" 394042394042","quantity":1},{"product_id":23,"quantity":1,"size_key":" 394042394042"}],"retailer_id":20,"status":"initial"}
```

just need value of  orderItems as

```
"[{"product_id":19,"size_key":" 394042394042","quantity":1},{"product_id":23,"quantity":1,"size_key":" 394042394042"}]"
```

" " mising

Comment: i want orderItems values in String " " .